How to Set Exception Rules for Slurm Executor in Snakemake?
I am currently working with a Slurm workload manager to manage and schedule jobs on our cluster. While most of my tasks are submitted and managed by Slurm, I have a few specific tasks that I would like to exclude from being submitted to the Slurm system and instead run directly on the local machine.
Here are the specifics of what I am trying to achieve:
Default behavior: All tasks should be submitted to Slurm.
Exception: Certain tasks (based on specific criteria) should run locally instead of being submitted to Slurm.

This is covered by localrules, see docs.

It is possible to change which rules are localrules using an if/else statement, which means you could make this depend on some config options. What you can't do is have some jobs from a rule run on the cluster and others run local (eg. depending on input file size) - you can only set this at the rule level.

SO is for programming questions

"SO is for programming questions" says the user with 95 posts about CSS! :-P

Regarding Tim's point, there is a directive version of localrule that seems to accept a lambda function.  Anyone know if that allows job-level control of local rules?  I'm living in version 7 for a while longer and don't have a good cluster test setup.
